# Ler um arquivo txt e armazenar o conteúdo em listas

Tags: c++, arquivo

Preciso ler um arquivo ".txt" grande e seu conteúdo encontra-se no seguinte formato:

```
1   12
1   13
2   5
2   6
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível ler o valor de cada coluna e armazenar numa lista, por exemplo:

```
Ler "1"
Armazenar o "1" numa lista
Ler "12"
Armazenar 12 numa lista
ler "1"
Armazenar "1" na lista
ler "13"
Armazenar 13 na lista
...
```

E assim por diante

Comment: Qual biblioteca do C++ você está utilizando para realizar a leitura do arquivo txt? A lógica disso basicamente é: ler todo o arquivo, jogar numa string, splitar ela numa array para identificar os elementos das listas e aí sim percorrer esta array distribuindo elementos.

Answer (score 2):

Para ter 2 listas, cada uma contendo os números de uma coluna o código abaixo pode ajudar.

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream file{"text.txt"};

    std::vector<std::string> columnA;
    std::vector<std::string> columnB;
    std::string string;

    int i = 0;
    while ( !file.eof() ) {
        file >> string;
        if (i++ % 2 == 0) columnA.push_back(string);
        else columnB.push_back(string);
    }

    for (auto s : columnA) std::cout << s << "\n";

    std::cout << "\n";

    for (auto s : columnB) std::cout << s << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```